# ArrayFormula to create a table of data from 1 column

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

I have the below formula and want to turn it into an array.

```
=INDEX($A:$A,ROW(A1)*5-5+COLUMN(A1))
```

I have tried it with the below attempt but only get 1 single cell result.

```
=arrayformula(INDEX($A:$A,ROW(A1:A)*5-5+COLUMN(A1:A)))
```

Google sheet link for example: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vqVl4r4PaKCh8YXf3e2Ie7JFrYresw3AB3hxq3UsEug/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- delete everything in range **D:H**
- paste in **D1** cell and drag to the right:

  ```
  =FILTER($A:$A, MOD(ROW($A:$A)-COLUMN(A1), 5)=0)
  ```

  [image: 0]

Comment: Thank you. :) that works perfectly. :)